# How to use java 6 to run ant script in Netbeans 7.4 Web Free Form Application

Tags: netbeans, ant

I'm using Netbeans 7.4 Web Free Form Application (It's a project from an existing code with an ant build script). My application require the code to be compiled using jdk 6. However Netbeans use jdk 7 when running the ant build script.

How to make Netbeans 7.4 using jdk 6 to compile java code when running my ant build script?

Pardon me for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Granted that you already installed JDK 1.6 and selected it in NetBeans as JDK 1.6 (Tools -> Java Platforms)...

Just:
- Open Project properties (right clic on Project name -> Properties)
- Select "Libraries" on left frame
- Beside "Java Platform" clic on the dropdown list and select JDK 1.6